# rspec passing instance as argument causes result with different object id

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test this example code:

```
SomeJob.schedule_job(title: title, body: BodyGenerator.new(recipient: user))
```

So the body of my `rspec` test is:

```
expect(SomeJob).to receive(:schedule_job).with(
  title: 'Some title',
  body: BodyGenerator.new(recipient: test_user)
).and_call_original
...
```

But I am getting the error after running the tests
and the only difference between expected result and actual result is the object id of the `BodyGenerator`

`-   #<BodyGenerator:0x00007fb188b50f68 ...`

`+   #<BodyGenerator:0x00007fb188bebe50 ...`

Without `and_call_original` we can use `be_an_instance_of(BodyGenerator)`
but here it's not the case

---

For more context. `BodyGenerator.new(recipient: user)` will return specific message depending on the user type and other user's properties.

---

Comment: Can you dependency-inject a `body` variable into the parent method? That would be the easiest way to test this.

Comment: Or likewise, could you abstract `BodyGenerator.new(recipient: user)` into a separate method, and set your expectation based on this value?

Comment: Basically, could you provide more context? It's hard to provide conclusive advice when you've only shown 1 line of code.

Comment: @TomLord could you specify what do you mean under `dependency-inject a body variable into the parent method` please?

Comment: What is the context of this code? `SomeJob.schedule_job`? I'm assuming it happens somewhere inside a method, and my point is that you could potentialy *inject* `body: BodyGenerator.new(recipient: user)` as a parameter to that method. Maybe that makes sense or maybe not; it's impossible for me to say much with confidence when you're still only showing 1 line of code. If you show the context, I can give a more concise answer. Otherwise, I can only really speak in vague theoretical terms.

Comment: Do you _need_ the `.and_call_original`, though?  Presumably, it only pushes a job to a background worker queue to be executed sometime later. As such, the actual job is then not expected to execute inline and have effects on the rest of the method body. So you might as well stub the method, `expect(SomeJob).to receive(:schedule_job).with(title: "Some title", body: BodyGenerator)` (should work instead of `body: kind_of(BodyGenerator)`)

Answer (score 1):

`BodyGenerator.new` is returning a different instance of `BodyGenerator` in your test than in your implementation. As such, the two do not match.

You should instead mock `BodyGenerator.new` such that the returned instance in your implementation matches your test:

```
let(:body_double) { instance_double(BodyGenerator) }

before do
  allow(BodyGenerator).to receive(:new).and_return(body_double)
end

it "passes the test" do
  expect(SomeJob).to receive(:schedule_job).with(
    title: "Some title",
    body: body_double
  )
end
```

If necessary, you can then also set expectations against the params passed to `BodyGenerator.new`